# How to manually trigger a bindingHandler?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following bindinghandler in my DOM:

```
<textarea data-bind="value: responseText, pagedown: liveEditors['editor'], valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></textarea>
```

Binding handler js:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.pagedown = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    // when formatting is not enabled, this will be null
    if (valueAccessor() != null) {
        valueAccessor().hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", function () {
            $(element).change();
        });
    }
}
};
```

This binding handler is for pagedown formatting.  A moment ago, the formatting was displayed by default, so the `valueAccessor()` was always hit, as the `liveEditors['editor']` array item was non-null.

But now, I'm trying to stop this bindinghandler from running until a condition is met - when the user triggers "showFormatting", I'd like this bindingHandler to re-evaluate, as the array will have been populated.

Currently, the bindingHandler is hit one time on load, `valueAccessor()` is null (as expected - formatting is not enabled), but then it never gets hit again.

How can I manually trigger the handler from a function, or pass it an observable to watch before re-evaluating?

Update: Changed textarea:

```
 <textarea data-bind="value: responseText, pagedown: { editor: liveEditors['editor'], showFormatting: showResponseFormatting }, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"></textarea>

 <a class="response-button-container" data-bind="click: showFormatting">show editor</a>
```

JS:

```
self.showFormatting = function() {
    self.showResponseFormatting(true);
    buildEditor();
    runEditor();
};
self.showResponseFormatting = ko.observable(false);
```

Binding Handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.pagedown = {
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {

    var options = valueAccessor();
    var showFormatting = ko.unwrap(options.showFormatting);
    var editor = options.editor;


    // when formatting is not enabled, this will be null
    if (showFormatting && editor != null) {
        editor.hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", function () {
            $(element).change();
        });
    }
}
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `update` function of a binding handler will create dependencies on any observables that it accesses, as bindings are run inside their own computed observable.

So, you would possibly want to do something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.pagedown = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = valueAccessor(),
            showFormatting = ko.unwrap(options.showFormatting),
            editor = options.editor;

        // when formatting is not enabled, this will be null
        if (showFormatting && options.editor != null) {
           options.editor.hooks.chain("onPreviewRefresh", function () {
                $(element).change();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Then bind like:

```
data-bind="pagedown: { editor: liveEditor['editor'], showFormatting: myObservable }"
```

So, the idea is that you would set the observable to true when the editor is ready. Since its value is accessed in the `update` function, the binding will run again when it changes.

`ko.unwrap` is a safe way to retrieve the value when you are not sure if you have been given a plain property or an observable.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've just updated everything on my end and I can't seem to get the changing myObservable() to trigger a re-run in the binding.  I've triple checked everything... any advice?  I've updated my post to show what I've done.

Comment: You should be using the `update` function rather than `init`.  I had erroneously put `init` in my sample as well.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh man, I should have caught that.  All is working perfectly, thank you for your help!